# MSBuild & TFS2010 Find Dlls

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I am trying to create a custom MSBuild task that will run my nUnit tests either locally or during a TFS2010 build.  The script works great locally but I can't seem to find the test dlls on the TFS build server.  I'm using a task in the MSBuild.ExtensionPack to run the unit tests (again this works fine locally).

The Assemblies list is always empty.  TargetDir shows the path is "C:\Builds\2\Product1\ci.product1.acme.com\Binaries\" which looks right to me.  I also tried to kick off my target after the CoreCompile target instead within the AfterBuild target with no change.

I've probably made some stupid mistake but I'm in kill me mode at this point.  Please help.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunTFSBuild>false</RunTFSBuild>
    <SolutionDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..</SolutionDirectory>
    <ExtensionTasksPath>$(SolutionDirectory)\_shared\MSBuild\</ExtensionTasksPath>
    <TPath>$(ExtensionTasksPath)MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks</TPath>
    <NUnitOutputFile>$(SolutionDirectory)\nUnitResults.xml</NUnitOutputFile>
    <NUnitOutputFileAsMsTest>$(SolutionDirectory)\nUnitResultsAsMsTestResults.xml</NUnitOutputFileAsMsTest>
    <ToolPath>$(SolutionDirectory)\_shared\MSBuild\nUnit_2.5.7</ToolPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(TPath)" />

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">     
    <CallTarget Condition="$(RunTFSBuild)!='true'" Targets="NUnitTestRunner" />
    <CallTarget Condition="$(RunTFSBuild)=='true'" Targets="NUnitTestRunner;TFSNUnitTestRunner" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="NUnitTestRunner">
    <ItemGroup >
      <Assemblies Include="$(SolutionDirectory)\**\bin\$(Configuration)\*.nUnit.Tests.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="$(RunTFSBuild)=='true'">
      <Assemblies Include="$(TargetDir)\**\*.nUnit.Tests.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="SolutionDirectory=$(SolutionDirectory)" />
    <Message Text="ExtensionTasksPath=$(ExtensionTasksPath)" />
    <Message Text="TargetDir=$(TargetDir)" />
    <Message Text="TPath=$(TPath)" />
    <Message Text="NUnitOutputFile=$(NUnitOutputFile)" />
    <Message Text="Running nUnit tests from: $(Assemblies)" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try to change property RunTFSBuild

```
<RunTFSBuild Condition="'$(RunTFSBuild)'==''">false</RunTFSBuild>
```

2) Replace sections (it may be just cleaning of project, but it may be very important due to some limitations of CallTarget):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="NUnitTestRunner;TFSNUnitTestRunner" />     
<Target Name="TFSNUnitTestRunner" 
        Condition="$(RunTFSBuild)=='true'">
    <!-- TFSNUnitTestRunner Body -->
</Target>
```

3) If 1) and 2) willn't be helpful try to set verbose of the build to diagnostic (msbuld key **/v:diag**). Find all calls of TFSNUnitTestRunner in the log and you will see what is actually happened on TFS.

**EDIT:** **Assemblies** is declared as ItemGroup. Use **@(Assemblies)** to access items:

```
<Message Text="Running nUnit tests from: @(Assemblies)" />
```

Property **$(Assemblies)** will **always** be empty in your case.

Comment: Regarding 1 & 2, the target is running fine so these wouldn't help.  I have been running with logging verbosity set to diagnostics and don't see any helpful info.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you find calls to NUnitTestRunner and/or TFSNUnitTestRunner? If it is not then the problem is higher then you described here.

Comment: I have had these targets the entire time and they are running  (I haven't listed the entire MSBuild script in the post).  Within the NUnitTestRunner target the Assemblies is always empty when running on the TFS build server.

Comment: That was it, I was referencing the Assemblies item list as a property.  I knew it would be something stupid.  Thanks!